# How to group by first 2 words in a pandas dataframe column and count?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['blue apple werewolf', 'blue apple cat',
'yellow tangerine','blue apple dog', 'orange dog nectarine','black', 'green apple cat'] })
```

I want to group by the first 2 words per row in the `id` column and return a count of items that begin with those two words. If a column value doesn't have 2 words, it should only count the first word.

So the resulting dataframe should look like:

```
ID             COUNT
blue apple         3
yellow tangerine   1
orange dog         1
green apple        1
black              1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to get it using extract :

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['blue apple werewolf', 'blue apple cat',
'yellow tangerine','blue apple dog', 'orange dog nectarine','black', 'green apple cat'] })

dfx.groupby(dfx.id.str.extract('([^\ ]+[\ ]*[^\ ]*)',expand=False)).count().sort_values('id',ascending =False).rename(columns={'id':'COUNT'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close. But it adds `id` as a table value in the first column, and the results aren't ordered descending as in the example result I provided.

Comment: adjusted, this was not clearly mentioned in the question anyhow it's easy to extend, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask when asking further questions